# XSLT altering webpart rendering approach

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, xslt

in sharepoint 2007 i would like to know what is the best approach to build a webpart that has its style,but not controls, altered by a XSLT... what i want to do is to build a "skeleton" (lets say its composed by text box and a button) and implement what the button must do... but the web-designer can provide me a XSL and the webpart must apply the xsl, altering the design and style, but not the programming... any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

XSLT is better approach to provide dynamic design and when its required to provide the end user the facility to change the style of display anytime in future. Its good to implement with web parts where you are required to have multiple views like List view or search results. If you require a data entry form to be created i don't think xslt based web parts should be choice. unless until you are using Client object model(Java script API's)